# Can constant acceleration/velocity be written as $a_c$/$v_c$?

Tags: acceleration, velocity

I was wondering if constant acceleration, for example, could just be written as $a_c$. I have seen it written that way, but I was not sure if it was legitimate. I did a quick search on Google but to no avail, so I turned to the best website out there.

I am new to physics, so having the knowledge of properly writing functions is a big deal. 
And if that is how you would denote *constant acceleration* the would just $a$ for acceleration mean that the acceleration is changing, as in a slope on a graph?

Sorry if this is confusing!

Comment: You can write it *anyway you want*. There is not law of physics notation. The important question is *"Will this be understood?"* and the answer in this case is *"You'd better say what you mean by that."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As dmckee says in a comment there is no hard and fast rule for writing a constant acceleration or velocity, so it's up to you to make clear what notation you are using.

Having said that, if I saw $a_c$ I would not interpret this as meaning the acceleration is constant. When I see the notation $a_i$ I normally expect this to mean the components of the acceleration vector ($a_x$, $a_y$, $a_z$) or with multiple bodies the acceleration of the $i$th body. I've never seen a $c$ subscript used to mean that quantity is constant.

To the extent that there is an accepted convention constants are generally written using uppercase letters, so if I wanted to say the acceleration was constant I would use:

$$ a = A $$

and explain in the text the meaning of the constant $A$. Likewise for velocity, though since $V$ is sometimes used as the symbol for potential energy you'd need to make it clear in the text what you meant.

Comment: $a_c$ sometimes means [centripetal acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force#Formula).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: Yes, although that is of course a component of a vector as I mentioned :-)

Comment: Great information! I appreciate your help :-)

Comment: @JohnRennie I know, that's why I mentioned - because it was a concrete example of what you said.